# Salvar usuario e senha, cookie em um webview

Tags: android

Como posso salvar um usuário e senha no webview android?
Na página(web), é solicitado cpf e senha, para login. Após esta entrada, é gravado o cookie `vis_cod`, que é um parametro de retorno criado (na web) a partir do cpfe senha que foram digitados. Como salvar este parametro, no webview e acessar o app sem a necessidade de digitar o cpf e senha, sempre?

```
public class fanpageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fanpage);

        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);

        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mywebView.loadUrl("http://mydomain.com/domain");
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mywebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView myWebview, String url) {

                //Abrir telefone
                if (url.contains("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    myWebview.reload();
                    return false;
                }
                //Abrir Whatsapp
                else if (url.contains("api.whatsapp")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    myWebview.reload();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    myWebview.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

/*                myWebview.loadUrl(url);
                return false;*/
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Não me recordo se o webview permite o armazenamento de cookies. Eu olhei rapidamente na documentação e não encontrei nada parecido, porém pode haver sim. Mas, uma solução paliativa pode ser você conectar o JavaScript da sua página ao Java, e lá você salvar os dados nas preferências. Aí no início da sua página HTML você faz o JavaScript pegar os dados, ver se eles estão nulos e setar nos campos e clicar no botão. Segue um possível exemplo!

```
//MainActivity.java

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.preference.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        JI ji = new JI(); //Declaração da classe feita abaixo
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(ji, "JI");
        //Neste ponto você pode substituir pelo seu site eu fiz assim para facilitar o exemplo. O código do site está sendo retornado pelo método.
        webview.loadData(getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }

    private String getHtml(){
        String html = new String();
        html += "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        html += "<html>";
            html += "<head>";
                html += "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/>";
                html += "<title>Página Teste</title>";
            html += "</head>";
            html += "<body>";
                html += "<form>";
                    html += "Login: <input type=\"text\" id=\"login\"/>";
                    html += "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"btn\"/>";
                html += "</form>";
                html += "<script>";
                    html += "document.querySelector(\"#btn\")";
                    html += ".addEventListener(\"click\", function(){";
                        html += "JI.setSection(document.querySelector(\"#login\").value)";
                    html += "});";
                    html += "let login = JI.getSection();";
                    html += "if(login != null) {"+
                                "document.querySelector(\"#login\").value = login;"+
                                "//document.querySelector(\"#btn\").click()"+
                            "}";
                html += "</script>";
            html += "</body>";
        html += "</html>";
        return html;
    }

    private class JI {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void setSection(String login) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("test", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("login", login);
            boolean b = editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b ? "Guardado" : "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getSection() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("test", 0);
            String result = prefs.getString("login", null);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Segue a main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Como vocês podem perceber o código é bem simples, mas acho que deu para entender a ideia geral do que disse!